# Using Nodejs and React how do you display a Modal dialog from inside a TopNav dropdown

Tags: node.js, reactjs, dialog, modal-dialog

I have a TopNav file which displays the items across the top of my page.  When the user clicks their icon a dropdown menu appears.  When they select "About" from the menu  I want a modal dialog to appear with the information in it.

The closest I have managed to get is by using an actual button instead of the dropdown menu item.  Also, pressing the button displays a modal only in the small window area with the dropdown instead of the in the center of the screen.

Here is the code for the TopNav.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { logoutUser } from "../../../actions/authActions";
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import "./TopNav.scss";

import AboutModal from "../MainContent/AboutModal/AboutModal";

class TopNav extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        isShowing: false
    }
}

state = {
    dropdown: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", this.handleClick, false);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener("mousedown", this.handleClick, false);
  }

  // Close dropdown when click outside
  handleClick = e => {
    if (this.state.dropdown && !this.node.contains(e.target)) {
      this.setState({ dropdown: !this.state.dropdown });
    }
  };

  onLogoutClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.logoutUser(this.props.history);
    window.location.href = "/";
  };

  handleProfileClick = e => {
    this.setState({ dropdown: !this.state.dropdown });
  };


  openModalHandler = () => {
    this.setState({
        isShowing: true
    });
  }
  closeModalHandler = () => {
    this.setState({
        isShowing: false
    });
  } 
  toggleModal = e => {
    this.setState({ modal: !this.state.modal });
  };

  // Show Side Nav
  toggleMenu = e => {
    let sideNav = document.querySelector(".side");
    sideNav.classList.remove("invisibile");

    let hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger-top-menu");
    hamburger.classList.remove("hamburger-visible");

    let rightSide = document.querySelector(".right");
    rightSide.classList.remove("no-side");

    let rightSideRight = document.querySelector(".right-top");
    rightSideRight.classList.remove("right-top-visibile");
  };

  state = {
    show: false,
  }

  showModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      show: !this.state.show
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { name, email } = this.props.auth.user;

    return (
      <nav className="top-nav" ref={node => (this.node = node)}>
        <div className="left-top">
          { this.state.isShowing ? <div onClick={this.closeModalHandler} className="back-drop"></div> : null }
          <i
            onClick={this.toggleMenu}
            className="material-icons hamburger-top-menu"
          >
            menu
          </i>
          <Link to="/dashboard">
            <h1 className="brand-header">
              TowTech Web
            </h1>
          </Link>
        </div>
        <ul className="right-top">
          <li>
            <div className="email">
              <p>Signed in as {email}</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div className="profile" onClick={this.handleProfileClick}>
              <span>{name !== undefined && name.split("")[0]}</span>
            </div>
            {this.state.dropdown ? (
              <ul className="dropdown">
                <p>Hello, {name !== undefined && name.split(" ")[0]}</p>
                <Link to="/dashboard">
                  <li>Home</li>
                </Link>
                <Link to="/dashboard">
                  <li>Profile</li>
                </Link>
                <Link to="/dashboard">
                  <li>Administration</li>
                </Link>
                <Link to="/about">
                  <li>About</li>
                </Link>
                <button className="open-modal-btn" onClick={this.openModalHandler}>About Button</button>
                <AboutModal
                  className="modal"
                  show={this.state.isShowing}
                  close={this.closeModalHandler}>
                      This is text for the modal dialog. I can't get it to display in the center of the screen, or with the actual drop down menu item.
                </AboutModal>
              {/*
                <Link to="/tasks">
                  <li>My Tasks</li>
                </Link>
                */}
                <li onClick={this.onLogoutClick}>Sign Out</li>
              </ul>
            ) : null}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { logoutUser }
)(withRouter(TopNav));
```

This is the AboutModal.js

```
import React from 'react';

import './AboutModal.css';

const modal = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="modal-wrapper"
                style={{
                    transform: props.show ? 'translateY(0vh)' : 'translateY(-100vh)',
                    opacity: props.show ? '1' : '0'
                }}>
                <div className="modal-header">
                    <h3>Modal Header</h3>
                    <span className="close-modal-btn" onClick={props.close}>×</span>
                </div>
                <div className="modal-body">
                    <p>
                        {props.children}
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div className="modal-footer">
                    <button className="btn-cancel" onClick={props.close}>CLOSE</button>
                    <button className="btn-continue">CONTINUE</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default modal;
```

Here is the AboutModal.css

```
.modal-wrapper {
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #d0cccc;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 7px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.17);
    margin: 100px auto 0;
    transition: all .8s;
    width: 75%;
}

.modal-header {
    background: #263238;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    text-align: right;
}

.modal-header h3 {
    color: white;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.modal-body {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

.modal-footer {
    background: #263238;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 15px;
}

.close-modal-btn {
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 0;
}

.close-modal-btn:hover {
    color: black;
}

.btn-cancel, .btn-continue {
    background: coral;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    outline: none;
    padding: 10px;
}

.btn-cancel {
    background-color: #b71c1c;
    float: left;
}

.btn-continue {
    background-color: #1b5e20;
    float: right;
}

.back-drop {
    background-color: rgba(48, 49, 48, 0.42);
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    transition: all 1.3s;
    width: 100%;
}

.open-modal-btn {
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

There are tons of tutorials and samples out there but all of them use a "Open Modal" button on the main page to display a modal.

Answer (score 0):

Your "modal" is currently just a div rendered within the dropdown, and you haven't specified a `position` css property on the element, so it defaults to `position: static`, which means it's positioned within the flow of the elements around it. If you want it to be positioned relative to the window instead, you can give it `position: fixed`. Alternatively, you can give it `position: absolute`, which will position it relative to its nearest positioned (i.e. non-static) ancestor. Since elements default to static position, if you haven't specified a position property (besides static) on any of the parent elements, the "nearest positioned ancestor" will be the viewport. Or if you want the modal to always be positioned relative to another container (e.g. the page container, rather than the viewport), you can set the container's position to `relative` or similar.

A better option in my opinion would be to render both the nav and the modal as children of the nav's parent component (rather than the modal as a child of the nav component), and use the parent state to manage the modal's show/hide prop.

```
class Container extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modalOpen: false
    }
  }

  toggleModal = () => this.setState(prevState => ({ modalOpen: !prevState.modalOpen }))

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TopNav toggleModal={toggleModal} />
        <AboutModal show={this.state.modalOpen} />      
      </div>
    )    
  }
}
```

This way you can position the modal within a page-height container, instead of positioning it within a nav dropdown.

Comment: Thanks, I will see if I can accomplish this.
Since I don't understand much of your response, it definitely shows I have still got lots to learn.  :)

Comment: I updated my answer to include some more explanation and an example. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks shannon.   It is a lot clearer.
Just some info on how the project is setup.    There is a Layout.js, SideNav.js and TopNav.js (all with corresponding scss files).   I am assuming the Layout.js is the main one which pulls together all the others to form the entire dashboard.  I would include your suggestion (above) in the Layout.js.  Showing the AboutModal is done by toggling the .isShowing (or in your example modalOpen).  Since the toggling is selected in the TopNav.js how would this be accomplished?

Comment: I once again got the modal displaying, but had to add the code to Dashboard.js.  I also had to put a button to click to get it to display.  Can not get it to display by selecting the item from the TopNav dropdown menu.   This is pretty much what I had accomplished before, as my issue is displaying it in the center of the screen from selecting an item from the dropdown in TopNav.js.

Comment: So I guess what I am actually asking is how do I display a Modal on the parent nav when clicking a dropdown item on the TopNav.
So a change to this code:
<Link to="/about">
       <li>About</li>
</Link>
That current code calls a link to and /about route, which isn't what I need.  But I need to toggle the modalOpen (set to true) which is on the parent nav.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. If you can link to a sandbox displaying issue it will be easier to help.

Comment: From the dropdown menu in TopNav I want to be able to open the modal dialog which is in Dasbhoard.js

Comment: Why can't you give the nav dropdown item an onClick  handler that opens the modal? This seems to be the problem you're describing but it's not clear why that doesn't work for you.

Comment: Oh, I can.  I just can seem to set the modalOpen to true which would cause the model in the parent nav to become visible.

Comment: It solution ended up being passing the function used in the Dashboardjs handler to the props of the TopNav so that it could execute the function to update the state.

Answer (score 0):

It solution ended up being passing the function used in the Dashboardjs handler to the props of the TopNav so that it could execute the function to update the state.